# Need main to call functions in order, properly

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

```
def load():    
    global name
    global count
    global shares
    global pp
    global sp
    global commission
    name=input("Enter stock name OR -999 to Quit: ")
    count =0
    while name != '-999':
        count=count+1
        shares=int(input("Enter number of shares: "))
        pp=float(input("Enter purchase price: "))
        sp=float(input("Enter selling price: "))
        commission=float(input("Enter commission: "))
        name=input("\nEnter stock name OR -999 to Quit: ")

totalpr=0
def calc():
    global amount_paid
    global amount_sold
    global profit_loss
    global commission_paid_sale
    global commission_paid_purchase
    global totalpr
    amount_paid=shares*pp
    commission_paid_purchase=amount_paid*commission
    amount_sold=shares*sp
    commission_paid_sale=amount_sold*commission
    profit_loss=(amount_sold - commission_paid_sale) -(amount_paid + commission_paid_purchase)
    totalpr=totalpr+profit_loss

def display():
    print("\nStock Name:", name)
    print("Amount paid for the stock:       $",      format(amount_paid, '10,.2f'))
    print("Commission paid on the purchase: $", format(commission_paid_purchase, '10,.2f'))
    print("Amount the stock sold for:       $", format(amount_sold, '10,.2f'))
    print("Commission paid on the sale:     $", format(commission_paid_sale, '10,.2f'))
    print("Profit (or loss if negative):    $", format(profit_loss, '10,.2f'))

def main():
    load()
    calc()
    display()

main()

print("\nTotal Profit is $", format(totalpr, '10,.2f'))
```

I *need* the `main():` to call `load()`,`calc()` and `display()` in that order. However, the program stops after load. The output will merely loop the load without calc or print.

I have been instructed **specifically** to NOT place `calc()` and `display()` in the while loop block, tempting as that may be. Also note, that solves the problem but that is not the solution I am specifically looking for.

What do I need to do to make this program work properly?

OUTPUT SHOULD LOOK LIKE THIS:

```
Enter stock name OR -999 to Quit: APPLE
Enter number of shares: 10000
Enter purchase price: 400
Enter selling price: 800
Enter commission: 0.04

Stock Name: APPLE
Amount paid for the stock:       $ 4,000,000.00
Commission paid on the purchase: $ 160,000.00
Amount the stock sold for:       $ 8,000,000.00
Commission paid on the sale:     $ 320,000.00
Profit (or loss if negative):    $ 3,520,000.00

Enter stock name OR -999 to Quit: FACEBOOK
Enter number of shares: 10000
Enter purchase price: 5
Enter selling price: 500
Enter commission: 0.04

Stock Name: FACEBOOK
Amount paid for the stock:       $  50,000.00
Commission paid on the purchase: $   2,000.00
Amount the stock sold for:       $ 5,000,000.00
Commission paid on the sale:     $ 200,000.00
Profit (or loss if negative):    $ 4,748,000.00

Enter stock name OR -999 to Quit: -999
Total Profit is $ 14,260,000.00
```

HERE IS THE OUTPUT ERROR I AM GETTING:

```
====== RESTART: C:\Users\Elsa\Desktop\Homework 3, Problem 1.py ======
Enter stock name OR -999 to Quit: YAHOO!
Enter number of shares: 10000
Enter purchase price: 10
Enter selling price: 100
Enter commission: 0.04

Enter stock name OR -999 to Quit: GOOGLE
Enter number of shares: 10000
Enter purchase price: 15
Enter selling price: 150
Enter commission: 0.03

Enter stock name OR -999 to Quit: -999

Stock Name: -999
Amount paid for the stock:       $ 150,000.00
Commission paid on the purchase: $   4,500.00
Amount the stock sold for:       $ 1,500,000.00
Commission paid on the sale:     $  45,000.00
Profit (or loss if negative):    $ 1,300,500.00

Total Profit is $ 1,300,500.00
>>>
```

Comment: from your description, it seems to work just as intended.
Can you be more specific of your problem?
`load`, `calc`, `display` are called sequentially, next one is called after previous has ended (returned from the call). 

Are you sure you correctly understand how functions & loops work ?

Comment: You are using `globals` a lot. It would be much better if you would pass them as function arguments.

Comment: That's the third post with practically the same code in a few days. What restrictions do you guys have?

Comment: your teacher seems to direct you to use lists to store values. You're currently losing all the values since they're overwritten by the last one (and name is always -999).

Comment: If the program worked properly (which it doesn't) it would ask for inputs, calculate and then display the inputs immediately. Right now, it's just asking for inputs, then looping and asking for inputs again. And again. Does this make sense?

Comment: Are you allowed to use `dict`, `list`, or `class`?

Comment: My teacher literally said "take the calc() and display() inside the loop and move them directly into def main():" I asked him THREE times for clarification. That's what he said.

Comment: Wait, are you required to actually use functions? Or are you supposed to move in the *code* of the functions to `main`?

Comment: We're required to use functions.

Comment: So, ostensibly, def main(): should call load(), calc() and display() in that order.

Comment: Actually, main already does call those functions in exactly that order.  There's no "ostensibly" about it.  Why do you say that the program stops after load?  I ran it and it doesn't.  If you enter -999 when you're prompted for a stock name, the loop exits, `load` returns, and `calc` and `print` execute in the expected order.  The reason that no one is really helping you is that you are asking to "fix" a program that is already working the way you want it to.  Can you clarify what the problem really is?

Comment: See my edit on the way the output should look like.

Comment: Also, see my edit where I added my error-filled output.

Comment: Not allowed to use dict, list or class as we haven't learned them yet.

Comment: Your requirements do not make sense. The desired output requires at least moving the `calc` and `display` functions' *code* into the `while` loop. Otherwise, it's not possible to interleave input and output like this.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you are clobbering the variable `name` every time you execute the input statement.  You need to assign the result of input to temporary variable and check that for equality to -999, like this:

```
def load():    
    global name
    global count
    global shares
    global pp
    global sp
    global commission
    count =0
    while True:
        s=input("Enter stock name OR -999 to Quit: ")
        if s == '-999':
            break
        name = s
        count=count+1
        shares=int(input("Enter number of shares: "))
        pp=float(input("Enter purchase price: "))
        sp=float(input("Enter selling price: "))
        commission=float(input("Enter commission: "))
```

Now when the function returns, the value of `name` will be a valid stock name.

The second problem is that your teacher has apparently instructed you not to do the very thing that you need to do in order to make your program work.  If you can't put the functions that you need to call inside a loop, they can only run once.  In that case it is logically impossible to get a separate printout for each stock.  I can't help you with that.

Comment: According to his desired output, `name` is never used again after being set to `"-999"`.

Comment: Except it's used in the first line of `display`.  I just noticed that he said in one of the comments that he's "required to use functions" and then apparently forbidden to call those functions from inside the loop!  Maybe there is some kind of misunderstanding between him and the teacher.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment

```
take the calc() and display() inside the loop and move them directly into def main():
```

this is consistent with your expected output:

```
def main():
    name=input("Enter stock name OR -999 to Quit: ")
    count, totalpr = 0, 0
    while name != '-999':
        count=count+1
        shares=int(input("Enter number of shares: "))
        pp=float(input("Enter purchase price: "))
        sp=float(input("Enter selling price: "))
        commission=float(input("Enter commission: "))
        # calculation
        amount_paid=shares*pp
        commission_paid_purchase=amount_paid*commission
        amount_sold=shares*sp
        commission_paid_sale=amount_sold*commission
        profit_loss=(amount_sold - commission_paid_sale) -(amount_paid + commission_paid_purchase)
        totalpr=totalpr+profit_loss
        # printing
        print("\nStock Name:", name)
        print("Amount paid for the stock:       $",      format(amount_paid, '10,.2f'))
        print("Commission paid on the purchase: $", format(commission_paid_purchase, '10,.2f'))
        print("Amount the stock sold for:       $", format(amount_sold, '10,.2f'))
        print("Commission paid on the sale:     $", format(commission_paid_sale, '10,.2f'))
        print("Profit (or loss if negative):    $", format(profit_loss, '10,.2f'))
        # next loop
        name=input("\nEnter stock name OR -999 to Quit: ")

print("\nTotal Profit is $", format(totalpr, '10,.2f'))
```

It seems like an exercise in refactoring - moving function together into a single function.

Comment: You've moved the code from `calc` and `display` inside the while loop, rather than the function calls.  I would call that a step backwards as far as programming style is concerned, but perhaps you are right that this is what the teacher wants.

Comment: @PaulCornelius Agreed, it's not nice. It seems a lot nicer than the tons of `global` declarations, however. I would have used a `dict` to keep all the data, but it's against the one, clear instruction provided.